# parse VT100 text with colors (for regex)

Tags: java, regex, string, apache-commons, vt100

I'm using Apache [TelnetClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#TERMINAL_TYPE) to connect over telnet and want to change the encoding to plain text.

In trying to process [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vt100) responses, however `String` response comes with [color](http://www.mudpedia.org/mediawiki/index.php/VT100).  How do you remove the color encodings to get the plain text?

I end up with fragments like (just for illustration):

```
You say: confusing the hell out of bob.
482 636 [w]Sep 13, 2013 8:13:13 PM telnet.player.RegexWorker parseAndUpdatePlayerCharacter
INFO: You say: confusing the hell out of bob.
482 636 [w]
Sep 13, 2013 8:13:13 PM telnet.player.RegexWorker parseAndUpdatePlayerCharacter
INFO: 0mYou
Sep 13, 2013 8:13:13 PM telnet.player.RegexWorker parseAndUpdatePlayerCharacter
INFO: say
```

The problem being that the CSI color codes come along for the ride.  How can I convert the `String` encoding from VT100 to [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text)?

Java [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java) sample for illustration:

```
package examples;

/* ====================================================================
 * The Apache Software License, Version 1.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2001 The Apache Software Foundation.  All rights
 * reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *    distribution.
 *
 * 3. The end-user documentation included with the redistribution,
 *    if any, must include the following acknowledgment:
 *       "This product includes software developed by the
 *        Apache Software Foundation (http://www.apache.org/)."
 *    Alternately, this acknowledgment may appear in the software itself,
 *    if and wherever such third-party acknowledgments normally appear.
 *
 * 4. The names "Apache" and "Apache Software Foundation" and
 *    "Apache Commons" must not be used to endorse or promote products
 *    derived from this software without prior written permission. For
 *    written permission, please contact apache@apache.org.
 *
 * 5. Products derived from this software may not be called "Apache",
 *    nor may "Apache" appear in their name, without
 *    prior written permission of the Apache Software Foundation.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE APACHE SOFTWARE FOUNDATION OR
 * ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF
 * USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
 * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT
 * OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

/***
 * This is an example of a trivial use of the TelnetClient class.
 * It connects to the weather server at the University of Michigan,
 * um-weather.sprl.umich.edu port 3000, and allows the user to interact
 * with the server via standard input.  You could use this example to
 * connect to any telnet server, but it is obviously not general purpose
 * because it reads from standard input a line at a time, making it
 * inconvenient for use with a remote interactive shell.  The TelnetClient
 * class used by itself is mostly intended for automating access to telnet
 * resources rather than interactive use.
 * <p>
 ***/

// This class requires the IOUtil support class!
public final class weatherTelnet
{

    public final static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TelnetClient telnet;

        telnet = new TelnetClient();

        try
        {
            telnet.connect("rainmaker.wunderground.com", 3000);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        IOUtil.readWrite(telnet.getInputStream(), telnet.getOutputStream(),
                         System.in, System.out);

        try
        {
            telnet.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

However, depending on the server you connect to, the response won't be plain-text -- the code above is just for illustration purposes to show [usage](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java) for `ApacheTelnet`.

Alternately, is it possible to set the Apache `TelnetClient` instance to only accept plain text through the `TERMINAL_TYPE` field?  However, this field is final...

The difficult is to run regex on VT100 colorized text -- how do you ignore the colors?  Or, work with just the plain text string?

Comment: while non-free (as in beer), this looks interesting:  http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jniwrapper/javadoc/com/jniwrapper/AnsiString.html

Comment: Is it not sufficient to replace all occurrences of `"\\e\\[[0-9;]*m"` with an empty string?